# Spring @value property: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap' to required type 'java.util.Map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I have a service with this spring property:

```
@Value("#{${table.to.key.order.by: {'table': {'key' , 'order'}}}}")
private Map<String, Map.Entry<String, String>> tableToKeyOrderMap;
```

for some reason I'm getting this error in the startup:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tableService': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tableToKeyOrderMap'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: 
Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap' to required type 'java.util.Map'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList' to required type 'java.util.Map$Entry': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your value from `@Value("#{${table.to.key.order.by: {'table': {'key' , 'order'}}}}")` to `@Value("#{${table.to.key.order.by: {'table': {'key' : 'order'}}}}")`

`{'key' , 'order'}` is read as `List`